# How to backup my Macbook documents on an external drive, always adding?

Tags: itunes, hard-drive, photos.app, imovie

My MacBook drive size is 120GB. Every few months I empty the photo library, I delete my GarageBand recordings and empty the iTunes resources—all these after I copy them on an external hard drive. So, nothing is lost.

But this ends in duplicated documents on my external hard drive. For instance, I always copy the whole photo library, but on my MacBook I do not delete the `Favorites` album.

What I want to do is: to have one file on my external hard drive for each of the following libraries:

- iMovie library
- Photos library
- iTunes library
- iBooks (?) — Not really sure where they are stored, but would be nice to back up these as well

Then, when I want to free up the space on my MacBook, I want to *merge* the MacBook libraries (iMovie, Photos, iTunes and iBooks) into my external hard drive libraries, but *without* deleting anything from my hard drive and keeping the metadata (such as edited photos and so on). For instance, if I deleted a photo from my MacBook which appears in the HDD library, I don't want it to be deleted there as well.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Time Machine? You may want to read my [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268137/168832) here which gives a good breakdown of how Time Machine treats data such as your Photos library. This may give you some context re your question above.

Comment: @Monomeeth I think the Time Machine requires a whole drive (am I wrong?). I have a 5TB drive and I want to use it for other documents as well.

Comment: @Monomeeth It says *The disk must be erased before it can be used...* (because of incompatible file system).

Comment: @Monomeeth TM doesn't work so well as an archiving solution as it automatically deletes old backups

Comment: No, TM doesn't necessarily need a whole drive. You can manually copy data across to the same drive if you wish, although you'd probably be better off partitioning the drive so that you have a dedicated TM backup partition and another partition for manual backups, documents, etc. As for your second issue re the incompatible file system, you probably can't do anything about that (at least not anything I'd recommend), except reformat the drive. Of course you'd have to backup the data on it before doing that.

Comment: *Of course you'd have to backup the data on it before doing that.*–Exactly... That's not something I can do right now.

Comment: One word of caution though - if you have a MacBook with only 120GB storage, and you're using a 5TB drive to augment that, then you _really_ need a backup strategy in place for both the 120GB drive and the 5TB drive. Basically, you're at risk of something going wrong with either drive and not being protected against data loss. In other words, what I'm saying is that at the very least you need to get another external drive for your backups.

Comment: @Monomeeth I know it's bad, but I assume that the external HDD won't break. Does the Time Machine store and display all the previous photos which were backed up before even later I deleted them because my Macbook size is not that big?

Comment: @patrix Granted, that is a risk if you let it get to that point (i.e. TM having to delete old backups). Ideally you would have two simultaneous TM backup drives that are alternated regularly (so one is always offsite) and then you'd purchase additional drives when they're eventually full. But of course most people don't do this.

Comment: @Monomeeth OK, but what I really need right now it's simply storing the photos and iMovie projects on my HDD, without duplicates, from all the time (bigger than 120GB) and adding more when I free up my Mac drive.

Comment: Yes, TM does do that so long as you don't let it get to the point of having to delete old backups because it runs out of space on the backup drive. That's effectively what @patrix was warning about (and he's absolutely correct).